# Piping find into another find does not work

Tags: shell, find

Here's my use case:

**Search the entire machine, and find any directory that is named X**

Of course, this line works:

```
find / -type d -name "X"
```

However, it's a little slow and I assume it uses a lot of resources.

To increase its speed, I thought about piping finds into one another to filter down possible search results. For example, only find directories that have an uppercase first letter in the root, then inside them find directories that are named **X**.

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "/[A-Z]*" | xargs find -type d -name "X"
```

However, this did not work.

I already looked at [how to pipe find's output into another find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101978/how-to-pipe-finds-output-into-another-find) but I could not find piping instructions for a couple of finds.

How can I pipe find into another find?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* run `find` on the result of another `find`, but not with that syntax.

> ```
> find / -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "/[A-Z]*" | xargs find -type d -name "X"
> ```

First, you can't use `xargs` like that on the output of `find` for any command, `find` or otherwise, unless none of the file names it outputs contain any whitespace characters, quotes, or backslashes (or non-characters with some implementations).

You can only use `xargs` with the non-standard `-0` option on the output of `find -print0` (`-print0` also non-standard) if you want to be able to process arbitrary files. The output of `find -print` itself is simply not post processable (see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)).

Also, here, `xargs` will *append* the file paths to the second `find` command, and put them after the predicates that make up the filtering criteria. The list of files `find` is to operate on must be given *before* any predicate.

More generally, using `xargs` on the output of `find` is rarely needed, as `find` has its own builtin (and more reliable and often more efficient) support to run commands on the files it finds with its `-exec`/`-ok` (and for some `-execdir`/`-okdir`) predicates.

But like with `xargs`, you need to make sure the list of files for the second `find` comes before the predicates, so it would have to be:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:upper:]]*' -type d -exec sh -c '
   exec find "$@" -name X -type d' sh {} +
```

Where we use the `-exec cmd {} +` form of `-exec` which like `xargs` passes as many possible paths as possible to `cmd` but also can only pass them at the end. `sh` is used to move those in the right place for the second `find`.

Also note that `-name` matches on the name of the file, not its full path (for which you need `-path`). So we need `[[:upper:]]*` not `/[[:upper:]]*` (nor `[A-Z]*` where what it matches on is often rather random depending on the locale) to match on filenames that start with an uppercase letter.

With the next version of GNU `find` (or its current development version), you'd also be able to do:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:upper:]]*' -type d -print0 |
  find -files0-from - -name X -type d
```

Here, you could do it whole with one `find` invocation though:

```
find / -path '/[![:upper:]]*' -prune -o -name X -type d -print
```

Where we tell `find` to prune the branches of the tree that start with directories in `/` whose name starts by any character other than an uppercase letter before looking for directory named X.

Note that with some `find` implementations on some systems (including GNU `find` on GNU systems), `*` may fail to match parts of file names that are not valid text in the current locale.

For example, the command above would find `/stéphane/X` even though `s` is not an uppercase letter if that `é` was encoded in iso8859-1 and the current locale was using UTF-8 as its charmap (where the 0xe9 byte there could not  be decoded into a character so `*` couldn't match across it), and the first command would fail to find `/Stéphane/X` for the same reason.

`zsh` globs don't have this kind of problem as the treat each byte that can't be decoded into a character as if it was an undefined character, so you could do:

```
print -rC1 /[[:upper:]]*/**/X(ND/)
```

Or as a slight optimisation if you don't need the list to be `o`rdered:

```
print -rC1 /[[:upper:]]*/**/X(ND/oN)
```

Note that it would include `/SymLink/.../X` dirs. To avoid that:

```
(){print -rC1 $^@/**/X(ND/oN)} /[[:upper:]]*(N/oN)
```

or:

```
print -rC1 /[[:upper:]]*(N/oNe['reply=($REPLY/**/X(ND/oN)'])
```

Which are like the two stage `find` approaches: find the directories whose name starts with an uppercase letter in one glob and then all the X dirs in them as separate globs.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is to find subdirectories under `/` that have an upper-case first letters, and then extract the pathnames of subdirectories in these that are called `X`.

With `find`, I would do this like so, assuming there are not many thousands of directories in `/` with upper-case first letter,

```bsh
find /[[:upper:]]*/X -prune -type d -print
```

Above, we call `find` with a set of top-level search paths.  These pathnames happen to correspond the the directory names that we are actually looking for.  The sole task of `find` becomes to investigate each of these and print the ones that are directories.

You may also skip `find` completely an instead just use

```bsh
printf '%s\n' /[[:upper:]]*/X/
```

The only difference here is that the pattern may match symbolic links to directories.  If that matters to you, you could do a more explicit test on the matching names, and tell the shell (which I'm going to assume is `bash`) to also match hidden names:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

for name in /[[:upper:]]*/X/; do
    [ -L "$name" ] && continue
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

---

After re-reading you question several times, I realized that I don't know whether you want to make the search for `X` *recursive* or not.  In the above discussion, I have assumed that you do *not* want to search recursively.

If you *do* want to search recursively, then you would use

```bsh
find /[[:upper:]]* -name X -type d -print
```

There is nothing that can make this faster unless you restrict the search to even fewer top-level search paths, or prune known paths under which you *know* you don't want to search, e.g. to avoid entering any `tmp` directory,

```bsh
find /[[:upper:]]* -name X -type d -print -o -name tmp -prune
```

You may want to restrict the search to a single file-system:

```bsh
find /[[:upper:]]* -xdev -name X -type d -print -o -name tmp -prune
```

Here, the the search from a top-level  search path would never cross a file-system boundary.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, thanks. I deleted the initial bits in favor of the more simple approach.

Comment: Note that `find /[[:upper:]]*/X -prune -type d -print` will also find `/SymLink/X` if `/SymLink` is a symlink to a directory that contains a `X` directory.

Comment: Not sure how `/[[:upper:]]*/X` is relevant, since they're clearly running a regular recursive `find` to find the `X` in the question. `[[:upper:]]*/**/X/` might work in the shells that have it (along with the symlink caveats).

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, that's how I interpreted "For example, only find directories that have an uppercase first letter in the root, then inside them find directories that are named X."  Whatever command they attempted wasn't, according to them, doing what they wanted, so I was not looking too carefully at them.  I did however look at the recursive case later, as is evident from reading my answer. I didn't want to write too much about any _particular_ shell, as they don't say what shell they are using.